# Whathappens to the Ricci curvature, the scalar curvature, and Einstein tensor if I change the signs in the def of the Riemann curvature tensor?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, general-relativity

I noticed some books define the Riemann curvature tensor with opposite signs on all $3$ terms. I wonder what happens to the Ricci curvature, the scalar curvature, and the Einstein tensor when using one or  other definition? Would they also change sign? And if I change the signs of the metric from mostly plus to mostly minus?

Comment: I suggest testing this yourself. Use the Riemann curvature of a sphere.

Comment: @Deane I just analysed it by looking at the definitions.. Am I correct to say if I change only the definition of the Riemann tensor by a sign then the Ricci curvature changes since it just a contraction and so do the Ricci scalar and the Einstein tensor provided that I don't change their definitions?

Comment: And if I change only the metric signature considering that I know already that the christofel symbols don't change,... The Ricci curvature does not change, the Ricci scalar changes because it is multiplied by the inverse metric and contracted while the Einstein tensor does not change because the change in sign of the Ricci scalar and the metric that appear multiplying cancelled each other out